# Android - Auto starting an activity after some duration

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, accelerometer, autostart

I am new to Android.

I am having Accelerometer sensor data in one activity. I stopped the SensorManager after a shake has been detected. Now I need to restart the activity automatically after 5 seconds, the SensorManager has stopped. Is it possible?

or is it possible to start the current activity from the same?

Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code when `SensorManager` has stopped. It will restart the Activity after 5 sec when `SensorManager` has stopped.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks! i will let you know after trying this.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to restart the activity automatically after 5 seconds, the
>   sensorManager has stopped. Is it possible?

Yes it is possible using [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

When stopping `SensorManager` provide `PendingIntent` of `Activity` to `AlarmManager` with required delay to start Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, intent, 
                              Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
AlarmManager manager =(AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);  
manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC,System.currentTimeMillis() + 6000, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks. I will let u know after trying this.

Answer (score 2):

When you stop `Sensor`, you can start `Activity` after 5s by use `Handler` like

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
      startActivity(...);
  }
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Thread is used to provide delay.
Add the below code when your sensor stopped detected.

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

              //Start Activity here
            }
        },5000);
```